# Latest Repository

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I cloned the latest Plutus-apps repository:
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps

Then afterwards when uploading the latest version with commit hash:git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd

Terminal responds with:reference is not a tree: 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run

```
plutus-apps $ git fetch --all
```

prior to

```
plutus-apps $ git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd
```

The first one will make sure you have the most recent view of the git repository from upstream. The second will then checkout to the provided revision. `git checkout` does not automatically do a `git fetch`.